# Using @MockBean to mock an ItemReader with @BeforeStep Throws Exception to many methods with @Beforestep anotation. How do I solve it?

Tags: java, annotations, spring-batch, applicationcontext

I have my own Implementation of an ItemReader with two methods.

```
public class Reader implements ItemReader<Integer> {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private Iterator<Integer> iterator;

    @Override
    public Integer read() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            return iterator.next();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void init(StepExecution stepExecution){
        List<Integer> integerList = (List<Integer>)stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get(CKEY_ERROREVENT_IDS);
        this.iterator = integerList.iterator();
    }
}
```

When I try to run this within a spring-batch context and mocking the ItemReader with `@MockBean` the application context throws:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: found more than one method on target class [Reader$MockitoMock$368106910] with the annotation type [BeforeStep].

Below is how I start the job.

```
@MockBean
private Reader reader;

@Test
public void readerTest(){
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("triggerId", UUID.randomUUID().toString()).toJobParameters();
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(processEventJob, jobParameters);
}
```

Comment: Could it be related to this post?
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/98067-beforestep-in-abstract-class, since mockito creates a subclass of the class-to-mock at runtime?

Comment: No I have seen the post and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Could you also post the code for the ErrorEventReader class? That seems to be the class you are creating the actual mock of? Does it extend Reader?

Comment: This is what it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce your issue. After that, I've replaced the mock with a child class of your Reader.

```
@Component
public class ChildReader extends Reader{

    public void init(StepExecution stepExecution){
        super.init(stepExecution);
    }
}
```

This gives the same exception. 
At runtime, Mockito also creates as subclass of your Reader. I think that this is causing your problem.

In this post, the same issue as described:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/98067-beforestep-in-abstract-class
I cannot find any reference to it being fixed.

What you can do to resolve this issue is extract the code you wish to mock to a separate class and mock that class. One logical place for it would be a StepExecutionListener. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html

Hope this helps....

Comment: No sorry to say i do not think it does. I'm trying to just test my job flow before the @Beforestep was introduced it worked perfectly and I was hoping to find a fix for it. But at least you have come to the same conclution I have so that means it is probably the right conclution. Thank you for all your effort! I really appreciate it! You gave me one small idea that might work but I will not test it until  wednesday. I will get back to this thread then to tell you how it worked out.
Thanks again!

Comment: Nope my ideas was what you descripe above but got stuck with the same result. MockBean and Beforestep does not mix with inheritance. Would be nice if it ever got fixed. I scraped my tests, They were not really nessesary any more. Replaced them with integrationtests instead. But thank you very much for all your feedback! Have been really nice to have someone else come to the same conclution! It means that I could let it go so much faster. Instead of wondering what I did wrong.

Comment: No problem. Happy to keep people sane. :-)

Answer (score 1):

implement stepexecutionlistener interface in your class and override before and after step method this solves my problem dont use @beforestep

```
public class Reader implements ItemReader<Integer>,StepExecutionListener{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private Iterator<Integer> iterator;

    @Override
    public Integer read() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        if(iterator.hasNext()){
            return iterator.next();
        }
        return null;
    }

   @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution){
        List<Integer> integerList = (List<Integer>)stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().get(CKEY_ERROREVENT_IDS);
        this.iterator = integerList.iterator();
    }

   @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Should fix if you change your MockBean to be the interface instead

instead of

```
@MockBean
private Reader reader;
```

do

```
@MockBean
private ItemReader<Integer> reader;
```

You shouldn't need the contents of your concrete class if you are mocking it out.

Comment: It does not work to mock it out that is the point exactly with the @beforestep annotation mocking does not work........

Comment: @PlickPlick in your test, you have used MockBean which means you don’t care about the implementation of your “Reader” class because you are mocking it out! It could have 10 BeforeSteps - it doesn’t matter because it’s mocked out. I’m not sure why you’ve pasted the source code of “Reader” as it implements an interface that you want to mock implement! If you change the type of MockBean to what Reader is implementing like I’ve suggested it will still replace Reader with the reader mock you’ve defined by wiring on the field name. Please try

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to use `mock(ClassToBeMocked.class)`, instead of `@MockBean`!